XGBoost forecasting methods Python
I have developed a time series forecasting model which evaluates features of the dataset, date and date attributes, holidays, promotion for the products and some more features.
After training and testing the data I evaluate XgBoost, Prophet, a deep learning model and a regular smoothed average model derrived from a few journals.
In most of the cases XGboost performs the best out of those models, however, when using the trained model to forecast for >3 periods, the error evaluated against the actual demand underperforms in comparison to the Prophet model or even the traditional model.
It seems that XGboost is very good to forecast for 1 or 2 periods, but it underperforms when forecasted for more than those periods.
I trained multiple models to forecast for multiple intervals and I also tried to forecast further into the future based on the actual forecast (which leads to a error amplification.
I can't find a solution to this problem, any ideas?
